# Flowplayer RTMP Seek

Tags: rtmp, flowplayer, seek

Is there a way to start a stream file on flowplayer from a certain seek point (eg. 15th second)?

I tried both `$f("stream",...).seek(15);` and `streams: [{ url: ..., start: 15}]` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you choose jwplayer, this article may help:
http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439375